# Nested [ListView]s with lazy building possible?

Tags: flutter, scroll, nested, widget

Is it possible to let the inner `ListView.builder` build its children lazily? Thus, is there an option to achieve the lazy building without using `shrinkWrap: true` for the inner `ListView.builder`? Scrolling should be performed via the outer `ListView`.

Note: It is not possible to alter the internal structure of `_WidgetWithDescendantListViewBuilder`.

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            _WidgetWithDescendantListViewBuilder(),
            /*
              More children...
            */
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class _WidgetWithDescendantListViewBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  /*
    Properties corresponding to the nested [ListView.builder].
  */

  const _WidgetWithDescendantListViewBuilder(/* initialize properties */);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      /*
        Arbitrary arguments...
      */
      child: ListView.builder(
        /* 
          Properties are accessed here to provide values to the parameters.
        */
        itemBuilder: _itemBuilder,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: no, you can't do that

Comment: This can lead to massive performance penalties if I am not mistaken. It surprises me that there is no solution available.